# Svelte.js - How to rerender child components with new props?

Tags: javascript, forms, state, svelte

I am working on creating a multi-step form using Svelte.js but I've run into an issue rendering each form page with unique props.

Here is a simple demo to show you what I mean:

```
// App.svelte

<script>
    import FormPage from "./FormPage.svelte";
    let formNode;

    let pageSelected = 0;

    let formPages = [
        {
            name: "email",
            label: "Email"
        },
        {
            name: "password",
            label: "Password"
        }
    ];

    const handleIncPage = () => {
        if(pageSelected + 1 < formPages.length)
        pageSelected = pageSelected + 1;        
    }

    const handleDecPage = () => {
        if(pageSelected -1 > -1)
        pageSelected = pageSelected - 1;        
    }
</script>

<form bind:this={formNode}>
    <FormPage pageData={formPages[pageSelected]} />
</form>

<button on:click={handleDecPage}>Back</button>
<button on:click={handleIncPage}>Next</button>

<p>
    Page Selected: {pageSelected}
</p>
```

And here's the `FormPage` component:

```
// FormPage.svelte

<script>
    export let pageData;

    const {name, label} = pageData;
</script>

<div id={`form-page-${name}`}>
    <label>Label: {label}</label>
    <input type="text" name={name} id={`input-${name}`} />
</div>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(pageData, null, 2)}</pre>
```

When I run the application and inc/dec `pageSelected`, the `pageData` prop changes successfully - as can be seen in the `pre` element. However, the `label` and `input` elements are exactly the same as they are on the first page. The `id` of the wrapping `div` element and the `id` of the `input` element are also unchanged.

When I type into the `input` and change the page, the text remains the same.

My goals are: to rerender the `FormPage` component when `pageSelected` changes and have the `input` and `label` change their values based on these new props. It should also be the case that when I change pages, the text already typed into the `input` should update and be empty (since no initial value is given to the inputs).

Having done multi-step forms in React.js, I would use a unique `key` attribute to make sure my `FormPage` rerenders every time the `pageSelected` state changes. But I am unsure of how to do something similar in Svelte.js.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Having read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976936/howto-do-something-when-an-attribute-changes-in-svelte) on StackOverflow, I found out how to get the `input` and `label` elements to change as well as the `id` attributes. Here is my updated `FormPage` component:

```
// FormPage.svelte

<script>
    export let pageData;

    $: name = pageData.name;
    $: label = pageData.label;

</script>

<div id={`form-page-${name}`}>
    <label>Label: {label}</label>
    <input type="text" name={name} id={`input-${name}`}  />
</div>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(pageData, null, 2)}</pre>
```

However, the text inside the `input` still does not change.

Is there a way to also update the value of the input as well? It would be ideal for my use case to create an entirely new element every time the props change, but it appears that Svelte is only updating the few attributes that have changed on the same underlying DOM node.

Can Svelte be told to recreate elements in this circumstance?

**UPDATE 2**

So I have figured out a way to get the value of the input to change. Here is my updated `FormPage` component:

```
// FormPage.svelte

<script>
    export let pageData;

        import {onMount, afterUpdate, onDestroy} from "svelte";

        let inputNode;

        $: name = pageData.name;
        $: label = pageData.label;
        $: value = pageData.initialValue || "";

        onMount(() => {
            console.log("Mounted");
        });

        afterUpdate(() => {
            console.log("Updated");
            inputNode.value = value
        });

        onDestroy(() => {
            console.log("Destroyed");
        });

</script>

<div id={`form-page-${name}`}>
    <label>Label: {label}</label>
    <input type="text" name={name} id={`input-${name}`} bind:this={inputNode}  />
</div>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(pageData, null, 2)}</pre>
```

This solves the immediate problem of updating the input value.

I've added the `onMount`, `afterUpdate` and `onDestroy` functions to see how the component changes over time.

First, the `onDestroy` function is called, and then `onMount` after that. These both fire only once. However, `afterUpdate` fires every time the props change. This confirms my suspicion that the component wasn't being recreated.

Answer (score 8):

There's a simpler way to do this. The `pageData` updates in your `FormPage`, the issue is when you are using `const {name, label} = pageData;`, you are basically assigning the values of the `name` and `label` parameters in `pageData` to two constants, `name` and `label` respectively. These two variables are no longer bound to the parent component. In order to fix this, use `pageData` directly in `FormPage` like below.

**FormPage.svelte**

```
<script>
    export let pageData;
</script>

<div id={`form-page-${pageData.name}`}>
    <label>Label: {pageData.label}</label>
    <input type="text" name={pageData.name} bind:value={pageData.value} id={`input-${pageData.name}`} />
</div>
```

> Note: If you don't want the compiler to give you an `undefined` error if no `pageData` is passed, then you can initialize `pageData` as an empty object `{}` like so `export let pageData = {};`.

As for the `input` issue, the easiest thing to do would be to add `value` to `formPages`, and then `bind` the `value` to `pageData.value` as shown above in the `FormPage`.

New `formPages` data

```js
let formPages = [{
    name: "email",
    label: "Email",
    value: ""
}, {
    name: "password",
    label: "Password",
    value: ""
}];
```

Here is a working example on [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/061c0c0040214aa8a0c760053c6df2ec?version=3.12.1).

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Answer (score 6):

`{#key}..{/key}` solves the problem.

- https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key

In my cases, `Sizing` component is used to update size(font size, or line height etc) like your `FormPage.svelte`

```
<script>
import Sizing from '..../Sizing.svelte'

const pages = {
  'font-size': Sizing,
  'line-height': Sizing, 
  ...
}
const props = {
  'font-size': { min: 8, max: 20, step: 1},
  'line-height': {min: 1, max: 3, step: 0.1}
}
let currentProp // 'font-size', 'line-height' etc ..
</script>

<div>
  {#key currentProp}
     <svelte:component this="{pages[currentProp]}" {...props}/>
  {/key}
</div>
```

Whenever `currentProp` changes, Sizing component is updated, too.

`{...props}` is mapped to exported variables

```
// Sizing.svelte
<script>
  export let min
  export let max
  export let step
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it fixed my issue perfectly! I just had to do this:
{#key changedProp}
<ChildComponent {changedProp}/>
{/key}